# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk' when retrieving objects with formset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm trying to fetch forms for floorplans related to user's property's, and am really having some troubles with it.  Every time I get an attribute error of: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'

models.py:

```
    class Property(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text="This is the name that will display on your profile")
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='properties/', null=True, blank=True)    
        options=(('House', 'House'),('Condo','Condo'),('Apartment','Apartment')) 
        rental_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=options, default='Apartment')
        address = models.CharField(max_length=120)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        website = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
        lat = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        lng = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        coordinates =models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=501)
        active = models.BooleanField(default= True)
        date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

        def save(self):
            super(Property, self).save()
            max_length = Property._meta.get_field('slug').max_length
            slug_name = slugify(self.name)
            self.slug = '%s-%d' % (slug_name, self.id)  
            self.coordinates = geo_lat_lng(self.address)
            self.lat = self.coordinates[0]
            self.lng = self.coordinates[1]
            super(Property, self).save()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s-%s-%s' % (self.id, self.name, self.address)

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("single_property", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class FloorPlan(models.Model):
        property_name = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name='property_name')
        floor_plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        numbers = (('0','0'),('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6+','6+'),)
        bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
        bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
        sqft = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        min_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        max_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
        availability = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Use mm/dd/yyyy format')
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='floor_plans/', null=True, blank=True)    

        def __unicode__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.property_name)
```

views.py:

```
def property_floor_plans(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        user = request.user
        profile_type = ProfileType.objects.get(user=user).profile_type
        if profile_type != 'Property':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
        user_objects = User.objects.get(username=user)
        print user_objects
        user_property = Property.objects.filter(user=user_objects, active=True)
        user_floor_plan = FloorPlan.objects.select_related('Property').filter(property_name=user_property)
        if user_property:
            num_properties = Property.objects.filter(user=user, active=True).count()
            num_floor_plans = FloorPlan.objects.filter(property_name=user_property).count()
            num_floor_plans = num_floor_plans
        else:
            num_floor_plans = Property.objects.filter(user=user, active=True).count()
        print 'Number of Floor Plans %s' % (num_floor_plans)
        FloorPlanFormset = inlineformset_factory(Property, FloorPlan, fk_name='property_name', fields=('property_name', 'floor_plan_name', 'bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sqft', 'min_price', 'max_price', 'availability', 'image',))
        formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
    else:
        user = none
    context = {
        'user': user,
        'formset_floor_plan': formset_floor_plan,
    }
    template = 'dashboard/dashboard_property.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The error seems to come from:

```
formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
```

Here's the Traceback

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1_live/src/properties/views.py" in property_floor_plans
  103.         formset_floor_plan = FloorPlanFormset(instance=user_floor_plan)
File "/Users/balrog911/Desktop/mvp/mvp_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __init__
  855.         if self.instance.pk is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /dashboard-property/floor-plans/
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

I'm new to Django and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's a lot going on here..  lwhat line is throwing the error? can you post the last few lines of the traceback? Also, just wondering, the 'print user_objects', is that for your own use, or is that means to be displayed in the template?

Comment: @onyeka Just added the traceback and the line that seems to be throwing the error in the post.

Comment: I think I've seen your problem, but just to be clear, Can a user have more than one property?

Comment: @onyeka yes, a user may have multiple property's.

Comment: So what's the goal? Are they editing all the properties at once? The formset is meant to work with a single instance but user_floor_plan and user_property are both returning querysets.

Comment: @onyeka Yes, although I'm beginning to think it might make more sense to have a specific dashboard for each property that includes the related floorplans.  I definitely want to be able to have multiple floorplans per property though.

Comment: I think what you're saying is a better approach, main dashboard can have a list of all the user properties then something like /dashboard-property/1 can be for each property's floor plan. `def property_floor_plans(request, id)` where id is the Property id. I feel that'll be tidier.

Comment: also you you don't need user_objects, seeing as you've already defined the user as request.user.

Comment: @onyeka Thanks for the suggestion, I'll give it a try.  What do you think should be done if the user doesn't have any property's?  Maybe an alternate view for the first input...

Comment: Yes, you'll want to have another view for the properties list. If there's none, you can just leave a message in the template. For instance `{% if properties_list %} ... the list...  {% else %} You do not have any properties yet. {% endif %}` something like that.